# Why is GoogleApiClient starting a different activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-api-client

I have the following code which is part of a LoginActivity which is not the MAIN or LAUNCHER activity. This activity is started from the Application Class.

The problem is, after I press the Login button, the Dialog from where I choose an account pops up, I choose one, press the OK button, and afterwards my onStop method is called and the MAIN activity is shown. No other method (including OnConnected) seems to be called afterwards.

Is this a limitation of the GoogleApiClient where I can only use it from the Main Activity ? I haven't been able to find anything regarding this and I have tried changing the Activity to a FragmentActivity with no luck...

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_login)
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

@App
MyApp app;

@ViewById(R.id.layout_login)
LinearLayout layoutLogin;

@ViewById(R.id.layout_loading)
RelativeLayout layoutLoading;

@ViewById(R.id.layout_error)
RelativeLayout layoutError;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private boolean mIntentInProgress;
private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    layoutLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layoutLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mSignInClicked = false;

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Click(R.id.button_sign_in)
public void signInButtonClicked() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems setting this in the AndroidManifest results in GoogleApiClient closing the activity in which it resides if it is not the main activity.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```